# Is it possible to axiomatize classical logic with only two meta-variables?

Tags: propositional-calculus, axioms, metalogic

In the usual axiomatization of propositional logic with the $\to$ and $\lnot$ connectives, we have the modus ponens inference rule (from $p$ and $p \to q$ infer $q$) and the axiom schemes:

1. $p \to (q \to p)$
2. $(p \to (q \to r)) \to ((p \to q) \to (p \to r))$
3. $(\lnot p \to \lnot q) \to (q \to p)$

Of these, only the second axiom scheme uses three meta-variables. **I am wondering whether there is a way to replace this axiom scheme with one or more axiom schemes using at most two meta-variables.**

The axioms systems listed [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Hilbert_systems) all seem to need at least one axiom schemes with three or more meta-variables, even for different sets of logical connectives.

Comment: I guess not. My thinking : We should have a Premise Meta-variable & a Conclusion Meta-variable. When we have a Meta Axiom to refer to that , we should have at least 1 new Meta-variable. Other-wise , we can have no Meta Axiom.

Comment: It turns out my question was already answered at https://mathoverflow.net/questions/244594/number-of-distinct-variables-used-in-axiomatizating-classical-propositional-lo. Wajsberg's theorem mentioned in the answer is in fact a lot stronger: using only substitution and modus ponens, it is impossible to derive $(p \to (q \to (r \to p)))$ from any set of propositional logic tautologies using at most 2 propositional variables. I have not yet seen a proof of this result.